# Delete qmail doublebounce solution

Tags: linux, email

I use vpopmail and qmail on a Gentoo.

I have the domain "toto.com" (exemple) and need to delete the double bounces which are 99,99999% SPAMs. (I do not want to delete the "simple" bounces).

I can do this:

```
echo toto.com > /var/qmail/control/doublebouncehost
echo doublebounce > /var/qmail/control/doublebouncto
echo "#" > ~vpopmail/domains/toto.com/.qmail-doublebounce
```

Or:

Create a dummy email adress (ihateit@toto.com) and add it to the file `/var/qmail/control/doublebounceto`. Then add `|exit 0` to /var/qmail/mailnames/toto.com/ihateit/.qmail

A) Which solution is more adapted to delete these hated SPAMs/double bounced emails?

B) What are the differences between the 2 solutions? (outgoing traffic? performance? etc).

Thanks for your great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's almost same thing, although i'd go with 2nd solution as this doesn't require you to have vpopmail other then that i guess you'd want to put it somehow on smtp level rather having qmail-send delivery email to local and then dealing with that...

Answer (score 0):

I like the following, since it does not require vpopmail.

```
echo doublebounce > /var/qmail/control/doublebounceto
rm /var/qmail/control/doublebouncehost
echo "#" > /var/qmail/alias/.qmail-doublebounce
```

For your second solution, I think you can simply use "#" in your .qmail file instead of piping through `exit 0`.